# Best way to find whether a value exists in a JSON object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-5

I have a single level JSON to search through for the presence of a given value. Is there is a compact method provided in ecma5  for the same ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Parse the JSON string with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get a JavaScript Object.
2. Use [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator to check the member existence

   ```
   var jsObj = JSON.parse('{"p": 5}');
   console.log(jsObj);
   if ("p" in jsObj) {
       console.log("`p` exists");
   }
   ```

   **Output**

   ```
   { p: 5 }
   `p` exists
   ```

Comment: Had the same in mind, thanks for clarifying - just wanted to make sure there wasn't more to it that as specified in the json additions here https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/ECMA-5-Mozilla-Features-Implemented-in-V8.

Comment: The question was "find whether a value exists in JSON:". Isn't the accepted answer really finding "whether or not a certain key exists?".

Answer (score 2):

Since it sounds like you're looking for a specific value in an unknown key, assuming there that you already parsed your JSON, you'll need something more like:

```
function valueExists(jsObj, value){
    for (var key in jsObj){
        if (jsObj[key] == value) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: yep, I just needed to confirm that it was the most efficient way to do it, rest is simple logic so it's fine - thanks anyway :)

Comment: I don't know of a better way to do it. Someone else may.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON string with JSON.parse to get a JavaScript Object,
and do

Simplest check,

```
if(jsonObj['key']) {
}
```

### [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr4e9/)

Answer (score 0):

The shortest solution:

```js
    var jsObj = JSON.parse('{"v": 10}');
    if (jsObj.v==10) {
        console.log("`v=`"+jsObj.v);
    }
```